A novel where evolution from Neanderthals to us, and from us to superhumans is just by shedding facial skin to become less prognathous
I read this novel about 20 years ago, in English.
Even though the science is horribly wrong (which did bother me a lot) it is really a great novel.
It starts with an anthropologist finding that Neanderthals became Homo sapiens sapiens with a less prognathous face just by shedding facial skin and flesh. As if shedding skin and flesh would affect the shape of the skull ! And we are not direct descendents of Neanderthals. And evolution does not work so fast, over a single individual....
Moreover, in this novel, the fact that, once more, some people start losing facial skin and flesh and become even less  prognathous than us is taken as the onset of a new (and rapid) evolution to a new stage of mankind, beyond us, the ordinary Homo sapiens sapiens.
How the author, on that absurd premise, repeated twice at an interval of many tens of thousand years, manages to write such a gripping novel is really a "tour de force".

I'm not sure your commentary on this novel adds anything, nor makes it easier to find.

Maybe the book was written by a Neanderthal.

The mechanism of how it works in Darwin's Radio is not at all what the question describes. So it's a gross misremembering of details and then declaring how absurd those false memories are. The book is still science fiction but it's a bit more grounded in reality than that.

If I were going to criticize a science fiction author for bad science, it wouldn't be Greg Bear. He mostly wrote hard sci-fi, and went to great lengths to try to ensure scientific plausibility in those portions of his novels that weren't intentionally fantastical.

Nitpick: Many people are in fact direct descendants of Neanderthals.

I think you're thinking of Greg Bear's 1999 novel Darwin's Radio
From the Wikipedia page:

Built into the human genome are non-coding sequences of DNA called
introns. Certain portions of those "non-sense" sequences, remnants of
prehistoric retroviruses, have been activated and are translating
numerous LPCs (large protein complexes). The activation of SHEVA and
its consequential sudden speciation was postulated to be controlled by
a complex genetic network that perceives a need for modification or to
be a human adaptive response to overcrowding. The disease, or rather,
gene activation, is passed on laterally from male to female as per an
STD. If impregnated, a woman in her first trimester who has contracted
SHEVA will miscarry a deformed female fetus made of little more than
two ovaries. This "first stage fetus" leaves behind a fertilized egg
with 52 chromosomes, rather than the typical 46 characteristic of Homo
sapiens sapiens.
During the third trimester of the second stage pregnancy, both parents
go into a pre-speciation puberty to prepare them for the needs of
their novel child. Facial pigmentation changes underneath the old skin
which begins sloughing off like a mask.

This review confirms the Neanderthal connection:

Discredited anthropologist Mitch Rafelson has made an astonishing
discovery in a recently uncovered ice cave in the Alps--the mummified
remains of a Neanderthal couple and their newborn, strangely abnormal
child.


Yes, this is the one.

That is shockingly recent for science this bad.  I was assuming this was going to be some racist scifi from the 40s or something.
